# Prove that $\left (1+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )^n-\left (1-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)^n\geq 1$.

Tags: inequality, binomial-coefficients, natural-numbers

Let $n\in\Bbb N$, then $\left (1+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )^n-\left (1-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)^n\geq 1.$

Notice that,

$$\begin{align*}\left (1+\dfrac 1 {2n}\right )^n-\left (1-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \left (\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )^k-\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left (-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\left (\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )^k[1-(-1)^k] \end{align*}$$

I don't know how to get from there, because if $ n $ falls into an even number, all that goes to 0, and it is not greater than or equal to 1, but if $ n $ is odd if it is true. How do I finish the problem?

Comment: you have a wrong sign in there

Comment: As Exodd pointed out it should be $[1-(-1)^k]$ in the last branket. You almost done it and use the fact that $1\ge (-1)^{k}$ for $k>0$. Then plug in $k=0.$

Comment: Sure, but if the $ (- 1) ^ k $ is removed from the $ \left (- \dfrac {1} {2n} \right) ^ k $ the $ "k" $ is canceled.

Comment: @W.Wongcharoenbhorn I know that is true, but I have to arrive at that all that is greater than or equal to $ 1 $, but it would arrive at that is greater than or equal to $ (- 1) ^ n $

Comment: @JamesA.Agamez You were wrong at the first equation, its summand on the second term should be $\binom{n}{k}(-1/(2n))^k.$

Comment: That is what is put into the sum, what you say is there. Only then use the properties of the power, and take the $ (- 1) ^ k $ and multiply it with the $ (- 1) ^ {n-k} $. @W.Wongcharoenbhorn

Comment: @JamesA.Agamez No, you have $(-1)^{n-k}$ too, which is not to be there.

Comment: Oh yes, right. I changed that.

Comment: But in the same way, instead of remaining $ (- 1) ^ n $ there would be $ (- 1) ^ k $, and it would still not be possible to complete the exercise. @W.Wongcharoenbhorn

Comment: @JamesA.Agamez Sorry it is completed by using the fact that $1\ge(-1)^k$ for $k>1$. You then plug in $k=1$ and it is $1$ that stands out.

Comment: Thank you for correcting me and for giving me the suggestions to finish the exercise. @W.Wongcharoenbhorn

Answer (score 3):

You have the right idea. Combining each of the corresponding terms in the binomial expansions of the $2$ powers gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\left(1 + \frac{1}{2n}\right)^n - \left(1 - \frac{1}{2n}\right)^n & = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{k} - \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{-1}{2n}\right)^{k} \\
& = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{k}\left(1 - (-1)^k\right)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note $1 - (-1)^k$ is either $0$, for even $k$, or $2$, for odd $k$. Thus, each of the terms above is non-negative, so the sum is that of the positive terms. The first term (i.e., for $k = 0$) is $0$, but the second term, i.e., $k = 1$, becomes

$$\binom{n}{1}\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{1}(2) = n\left(\frac{1}{2n}\right)(2) = 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This means the sum's total is $1$ plus any additional positive terms and, thus, must be $\ge 1$ (basically as [W. Wongcharoenbhorn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/477320/w-wongcharoenbhorn)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4121858/prove-that-left-1-dfrac12n-right-n-left-1-dfrac12n-rightn-geq/4121877#comment8524541_4121858) suggests).

Comment: Thanks for contributing to the question and helping me.

Comment: @JamesA.Agamez You're welcome. Sorry about my earlier question comment when I indicated the incorrect small mistake in what you wrote in your question.

Comment: No problem, just as the mistake was mine. Again thank you very much. :)

Comment: It might be remarked that $$ \lim_{n \ \rightarrow \ \infty} \ \  \left (1+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )^n-\left (1-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)^n \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{e} \ - \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} \ \ = \ \ \frac{e - 1}{\sqrt{e}} \ \ \approx  1.0422 \ \ . $$

Answer (score 1):

At least for large values of $n$
$$a_n=\left (1+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )^n-\left (1-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right)^n$$

$$b=\left (1+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )^n\implies \log(b)=n \log\left (1+\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8 n}+\frac{1}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$b=e^{\log(b)}=\sqrt e \left(1-\frac{1}{8 n}+\frac{19}{384 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$
$$c=\left (1-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )^n\implies \log(c)=n \log\left (1-\dfrac{1}{2n}\right )=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8 n}-\frac{1}{24 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$c=e^{\log(c)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} \left(1-\frac{1}{8 n}-\frac{13}{384 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right) \right )$$
$$a_n=2 \sinh \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\sinh \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4 n}+\frac{13+19
   e}{384 \sqrt{e} n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$2 \sinh \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\sinh \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{4 n}\gt 1 \implies n > \frac{1}{8-4 \text{csch}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\sim 3.08774$$

Computed exactly
$$a_{10}=\frac{26372036801}{25600000000}=1.030158$$ while the truncated series gives
$$a_{10}=\frac{37939 e-37907}{38400 \sqrt{e}}\sim 1.030184$$